# Using UTL_FILE to pull data from an Oracle server to a local file system using JDBC?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, groovy, plsql

I need to consume a file that is being generated on an Oracle server and I have been told to get it using the UTL_FILE package.  I intend on consuming the file in a groovy script and have a connection to the database.  It is a simple text file and I'd like to pull it down to the server and consume it as I would any other text file but I suppose I am willing to read the data from some cursor if that is what needs to happen.

I am unfamiliar with PL/SQL and UTL_FILE.  Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

Comment: This will get you started with UTL_FILE: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Oracle/Reading-Text-Files-using-Oracle-PLSQL-and-UTLFILE/

Comment: Good resource.  So it is looking like I'm going to have to wrap each of the individual PL/SQL commands for opening the file and reading it line by line, closing and all of the exception handling code in CallableStatements...sound about right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the size of the file. If it is relatively small, then a stored procedure can read it all into one large field (VARCHAR2, CLOB or BLOB) and return that as a value.

Could also be worth looking into [external tables](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/ExternalTables9i.php) where you can select from the file just as if it was a plain database table.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would recommend trying the External Tables approach that Gary recommends - there is a good chance that this will meet your requirement, and will let you treat the data in the file as rows from a table in your calling code.

My next suggestion would be writing a function that encapsulates the UTL_FILE access, and returns the lines using PIPE ROW (that way you do not need to read the whole file into memory before the code starts returning rows to the client).

This function could either return a REF CURSOR (which JDBC can certainly handle) - basically a handle to the result set - or alternatively you could return a collection of object types.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE myType
 AS OBJECT 
    (user defined structure or something as simple as textline VARCHAR2(2000));

 CREATE OR REPLACE myTypeArray
 AS TABLE OF myType;

 CREATE OR REPLACE 
 FUNCTION myFunction(pFile IN VARCHAR2)
 RETURN myTypeArray PIPELINED
 AS
     lvRow myType;
 BEGIN
     UTL File code to open file and iterate over contents populating lvRow
         PIPE ROW(lvRow);
     end loop
     close file, etc
 END myFunction;
```

Then access this by casting the results of the function in a select

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE(myFunction(:filename))
```

If you don't have any parameters to the function, or can derive them from a table, you could even wrap this in a view.

The REF CURSOR approach pretty much wraps this SQL up in a function

```
FUNCTION myFunction(pFilename)
RETURN sys_refcursor
IS
   lCursor sys_refcursor;
BEGIN

    OPEN lCursor FOR
    SELECT  textline 
    FROM    TABLE(CAST(myFileExtractFunction(pFilename) AS myTypeArray);
    RETURN lCursor;

END myFunction;
```

But as all of this is essentially re-inventing external tables, double-check that they do not meet your requirement.